# Python shutil.move creating unopenable folders

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a simple script where I move a .mp4 file from one location to another. The print statements specify the source and destination path. The files are removed from the source path and I think are getting moved but these folders cannot be opened. It would be great if someone can look into this. Attached a picture for reference.

````
def moving_folders(divers,path_from):
    
    session_list = os.listdir(path_from)
#     print(session_list)
    for session in session_list:
        name_split = session.split('_')
        if name_split[0] == 'session':
            
            session_name = '_'.join(name_split)
            date = name_split[2]
            print(date,session_name)
            temp_path = os.path.join(path_from,session_name)
            files_in_path = os.listdir(temp_path)
            print("files_in_path",files_in_path)
            for file in files_in_path:
                if '.' not in file:
                    mp4_path = os.path.join(temp_path,file)
                    mp4_files = os.listdir(mp4_path)
                    for mp4 in mp4_files:
                        if '.mp4' in mp4:
                            src_path = os.path.join(mp4_path,mp4)
                            des_path = os.path.join(path_from,file.split("_")[2])
                            date_name = os.path.join(des_path,date)
                            print(src_path, "src_path")
                            print(dest_path, "date_name")
                            print("----[![enter image description here][1]][1]--------------")
                            os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(date_name), exist_ok=True)
                            shutil.move(src_path,date_name)```


  Source Path  C:\Dive_Videos\session_97cc7372_2020-10-30_140624\1_09196fa6_BROW_305B_fail\09196fa6_BROW_305B_fail_2.mp4 src_path
   Destination Path C:\Dive_Videos\BROW\2020-10-30 date_name


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33lOU.png
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the two builtin packages os or shutil to do the same

```
import os
import shutil

# Move a file by renaming it's path
os.rename(r'E:\file.mp4', r'E:\new\file.mp4')

# Move a file from the directory d1 to d2
shutil.move(r'E:\file.mp4', r'E:\new\file.mp4')
```

Answer (score 0):

The destination path was pointing to the destination folder. For `shutl`
to work we need to append the file name to the absolute path of the destination folder.

For example, my destination path was updated from `C:\Dive_Videos\BROW\2020-10-30` to `C:\Dive_Videos\BROW\2020-10-30\test.mp4` . This moved the file from the source path (`C:\Dive_Videos\session_97cc7372_2020-10-30_140624\1_09196fa6_BROW_305B_fail\test.mp4` )to the destination path. Even in the earlier case the files moved to destination folder but couldn't be opened.

`destination_path = os.path.join(des_path,date,file_name)` fixed the issue in my case.